# Svelte: Web components passing prop camel case

Tags: web-component, svelte, svelte-3

I am using web components generated by svelte.
I have props defined in camel case (someType) and the expectation was that the following should work but doesn't

```html
<my-web-c some-type="stringVal"></my-web-c>
```

Is this to be expected? Are there any options by which this can work?

I am aware that passing props as snake case and plain values does work like in JS (some_type)

```html
<my-web-c some_type="stringVal"></my-web-c>
```

or in JS (sometype)

```html
<my-web-c sometype="stringVal"></my-web-c>
```

But was curious about the camel case.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a camel case prop like this:

```
<my-web-c someType="stringVal"></my-web-c>
```

This [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b0347fae14344cf490b4dd53d46be527?version=3.24.0) shows different props types in action.  Kebab-case isn't currently supported.  There is an issue open for it [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3852).

Comment: For a web component generated by keeping customElement: true the above does not work i.e someType=''stringVal". It works only in svelte components.

Answer (score 1):

Passing camel case prop just works only in svelte components. It doesn't work with custom elements.

You can use as below;

```html
<my-web-c samplecomp = 'Sample Comp'></my-web-c>
<my-web-c sample_comp = 'Sample Comp'></my-web-c>
```